# Apache server error Ubuntu 18: Syntax error on line 1: <VirtualHost> directive missing closing >

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-2.4, lamp

I've been trying to get my Apache server running on Ubuntu, but in my

```
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/dev.lamp.test.conf
```

file I get this error when I run `apachectl stop`

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/dev.lamp.test.conf:
<VirtualHost> directive missing closing '>'
Action 'stop' failed.
```

My file looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost 10.0.2.15
191.168.56.103:80>
    ServerName dev.lamp.test
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/dev.lamp.test/public_html/
    ErrorLog /srv/www/dev.lamp.test/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /srv/www/dev.lamp.test/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm not sure what's going on. I've checked the other files in the directory and the VirtualHost tags are all closed properly. Thank you for any help! Please let me know if you need additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is clear, missing closing `>` at line 1 mean you need to write the `<VirtualHost>` tag on **one** line.

From doc, ip addresses must be **space** separated.

```
<VirtualHost 10.0.2.15 191.168.56.103:80>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That was it. Silly me. I appreciate your help.